# Have a function run when dependencies are satisfied

Tags: puppet

I have a function in puppet that creates a temporary folder to use as a scratch directory. However, because of how puppet works the function is run at compile time, and thus the folder is always created.

I would like to add a dependency to the function somehow.

Here is the function:

```
module Puppet::Parser::Functions
    newfunction(:create_temporary, :type => :rvalue) do |args|
        temporary = Dir.mktmpdir
        temporary
    end
end
```

Comment: What kind of dependency ? You are using mktmpdir and each time this function is called during the compile time, system call from Ruby will create a new temp dir.

Comment: I run an exec to determine if I should install a program. If the program does not run I don't clean up the folder. This means that every run I am left with a new empty tempdir that needs to be removed.

Comment: Does not compute. The `function` is run on the *master*, the `exec` runs on the *agent*. It's not at all clear what happens and what you expect. Please extend the question to describe your whole scenario.

Comment: I am running masterless, so the agent and master are one and the same. Perhaps this would be better as a fact that creates a single temporary directory per run?